# Can't boot system with raid1

Tags: ubuntu, boot, software-raid

I installed ubuntu server 10.04 on a PC with two HD drives 500 GB each. I used raid1 to provide data protection.

After the installation has completed, the system did not boot properly. I got the following error message:

```
ALERT! /dev/disk/by-uuid/$UUID does not exist. Dropping to a shell!
```

I tried the following scenarios:

1- Installing the /boot partition on a mirrored device /dev/md0.

2- Installing the /boot partition without raid1.

3- Installing the system without raid at all.

I got the same error in cases 1 and 2. However, the system booted as it should do in case 3.

Any idea what could cause such a problem? Can't I install ubuntu server on these HD drives with raid1?

Comment: At seems like there is a problem with the raid-configuration. Are you sure you installed the system into `/dev/mdx` and not `dev/sdx`? Can you provide the output of `sudo fdisk -l`?

Comment: @Bobby: I tried both cases: installing the /boot on /dev/mdx and /dev/sdx. These are the case 1 & 2 shown in the question. Currently, I can't provide the output of fdisk as I was trying to re-install the system. Which case are you interested in (1 or 2)?

Comment: Are you using a Soft- or Hardware raid? And was that the whole error message or was their also a UUID provided?

Comment: Ah, I see...markup ate it. Seems like there changed something from the installation...do you need an extra boot partition or can you leave it in `/`?

Comment: Thanks for editing the question! I am using Linux software raid (MD). For the boot partition, I can leave it in / if it will work :)

Comment: @Khaled: Try it, maybe that's a workaround. The only reason I can imagine is that the UUID is changing for some reason (or is wrongly written into the boot configuration or fstab, depends on where the boot process stops).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An all-RAID-1 installation is supposed to work out of the box (at least with the server installer). I don't know what could have gone wrong for you.

If you run into that problem again, try changing `root=UUID=…` to `root=/dev/md0p1` (or whatever the right number is) in the `linux` line at the Grub prompt.

If that doesn't work either, you can boot on one of the components of the mirror, e.g. `/dev/sda1`. Make sure to set the other component as faulty with `mdadm /dev/md0 --fail /dev/sdb1` before you do anything RAID-related. If you manage to get a command line, run `update-initramfs -u`. Then try rebooting on `/dev/md0p1`.

If you manage to boot on the RAID device, either figure out what the right uuid for your root partition is (it might be as simple as running `update-grub`), or alternatively set `GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true` in `/etc/default/grub` and run `update-grub`.